# placing existing sqlite database and reading

Tags: android, database

Where to place existing sqllite database in android folder structure? Is it drawable folder or layout folder?

I am not finding any solution for this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put it in the `assets` folder.
This way you can make sure it will be attached to your apk.
this is how you can copy the database file from the assets folder to your working directory:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}
```

now to read the database from the directory:

```
 public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}
```

Comment: when you copy the database file to the directory you want by the function i mentioned, you can open and read the database as a normal db file existing there.

Answer (score 1):

As name should indicate `drawable` or `layout` are NOT for database. If you want to distribute pre-set database with your app, then it's not relevant where you put it (aside that when you try to put it in `drawable` or `layout` you will not be able to build your app). Most sane place is `assets` folder. And there's quite nice helper that would help you with the task of setting such database for use with the app: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 0):

Path:  data -> data -> com.yourcompany.yourappid -> databases
or you can use Astro File Manager application to find the database on your device and to browse your device folder structure.

This code presents how to locate sql's DB file on your device:

```
var dbName = 'dbData';
var dbPath;
var dbFile;
if ( Ti.Platform.osname == 'android' ) {
    dbPath = 'file:///data/data/' + Ti.App.getID() + '/databases/';
    dbFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile( dbPath + dbName ); 
}
else {
    dbPath = Ti.Filesystem.applicationSupportDirectory + '/database/';
    dbFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile( dbPath + dbName + '.sql' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but u dint get my question. I have created one db in sqllite manager and want to bundle it with my app. So where shud i place it so that i can use it in my activity

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I place the sqllite database in the assets folder.
And for use it, you can copy it to "/data/data/your.application.package.name/databases/

Answer (score 0):

you should put your external database file in **assets** folder :

And after that make a Class for it.

```
package com.appgiudeextra.Database;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.appguideextra.Items.MasterItem;

public class DBConnect extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 public int GetCursor;
// ****************** Declare all the global variable
// ****************************//
 private Context myContext;
 public String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.appguideextra/databases/"; // path
// of
// your
// datbase
 public static String DB_NAME = "AppGuide.sqlite";// your database name
 static String ASSETS_DB_FOLDER = "db";
 private SQLiteDatabase db;

 public DBConnect(Context context, String db_name) {
    super(context, db_name, null, 2);
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        close();

    this.myContext = context;
    DB_NAME = db_name;

    try {
        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // System.out.println("Exception in creation of database : "+
        // e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // System.out.println("Database Exist");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream input = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
    // System.out.println(DB_NAME + "Database Copied !");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public boolean isOpen() {
    if (db != null)
        return db.isOpen();
    return false;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // System.out.println("My Pathe is:- " + myPath);
        // System.out.println("Open");
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        // System.out.println("checkDB value:" + checkDB);
        // System.out.println("My Pathe is:- " + myPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        // System.out.println("Closed");
        checkDB.close();
        // System.out.println("My db is:- " + checkDB.isOpen());
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public Cursor execCursorQuery(String sql) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        GetCursor = cursor.getCount();
        Log.i("Inside execCursorQuery try", sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Inside execCursorQuery exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return cursor;
}

public void execNonQuery(String sql) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(sql);
        // Log.d("SQL", sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.e("Err", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // closeDb();
    }
}}
```